# How to instantiate public members of a class and return it as a std::promise?

Tags: c++, class, std-future

I wish to instantiate public members of a class and return it as a promise.
This is what I am trying to do:

```
class A
{
public:
   int x;
};

std::future<A> returnPromiseA(int y)
{
   std::promise<A> promise;
   promise.x = y; //<- THIS IS INCORECT
   return promise;
}
```

`promise.x = y;` is an incorrect syntax.
What is the correct syntax for assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current C++ async classes cannot chain continuations so you'll have to do it other way:

```
std::future<A> returnFutureA(int y) {
    return std::async([y]{ A retVal; retVal.x = y; return retVal; });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! If I wish to read the members of a function which returns a future. How would I do it?

Comment: They are deep encapsulated in the function deeply encapsulated in `async`'s return value. If you want to keep track of construction arguments you used to create an async value, well, guess it can't be helped, you'll have to define a wrapper struct that, when constructed, creates a future and reports it readily but still remembers the arguments—and additionally allows to `set` them, changing the async value respectively, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

You can't access the members of the template type through a `std::promise`.  To set the value in a `std::promise` you need to use the [`set_value`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise/set_value) function.

That means you code should look like

```
std::future<A> returnPromiseA(int y)
{
   std::promise<A> promise;
   promise.set_value(A{y}); // construct an A with the desired value and set promises' value to that
   return promise;
}
```